# Showing all posts and custom post types by using a single category

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a post type with `CPT UI`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_matratze' );
function cptui_register_my_cpts_matratze() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'Matratzen', '' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'Matratze', '' ),
        );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'Matratzen', '' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
                "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "matratze", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,

        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "excerpt", "trackbacks", "custom-fields", "comments", "revisions", "author", "page-attributes", "post-formats" ),      
        "taxonomies" => array( "category", "post_tag" ),
            );
    register_post_type( "matratze", $args );

// End of cptui_register_my_cpts_matratze()
}
```

However, when I want to access the categories over a link in the my Frontend, I get no posts.

For example when you click on I get nothing back:

[Category](http://matratzenguru.com/category/dami)

The post is on and has the category `DaMi`:

[Post](http://matratzenguru.com/matratze/temperaturetouch-visco-komfortschaum-matratze)

Is my `CPT UI Post Type` wrongly configured? Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure but add 'menu_position' => 1 in $args.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: @DevDanidhariya I just clarified my answer! It is not about the backend menu, but the frontend display! Thx anyway!!

Comment: @mrquad: can you also share your `register_taxonomy` code.

Comment: @mrquad if my answer solved your problem, please mark it, thanks!

Comment: @Allen seems to have answered the q? (And another person has provided the same answer again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look over [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-categories-to-a-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/)

By default the category pages on your WordPress site will only display the default ‘Posts’ post type, so you need to add your CPT before Wordpress query the posts by adding the pre_get_posts filter.

added code here:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if( is_category() ) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('nav_menu_item', 'post', 'matratze'); // don't forget nav_menu_item to allow menus to work!
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's best to show in your answer what the article explains, in case this link ever 404s

Answer (score 2):

When you use Wordpress standard category to your custom post type, by default Wordpress won't show your custom post type posts on the category archive page. So you have to modify the category archive page query to include your custom post type.

Please include the following code in function.php file. Don't forget to change your custom post type name in the following code.

```
function add_custom_post_types_to_tax( $query ) {
    if( is_category() || is_tag() && 
        empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {

        // Include your custom post type
        $post_types = array( 'post', 'your_custom_type' );

        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
        return $query;
    }
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_types_to_tax' );
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

For this ,

```
function query_post_type($query) {
  if( is_category() ) {
        $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
        // post type get here
        if($post_type){
                // no more code here for by default
        }           
        else{
           $post_types = array( 'post', 'your_custom_type' );
            // custom type          
        }
        $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
```

I think use this function and it will be working . Any another issue comment for it.